# Understanding `this` in jquery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, this, bind

Javascript newbie here. I'm trying to understand `this` and `bind` within the context of [jquery event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/on/). I'm reviewing a piece of code from the todoMVC code [here](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/master/examples/jquery/js/app.js), and have a question.

**Let's look at line 56:**

`$('#new-todo').on('keyup', this.create.bind(this));`

**Code excerpt for context:**

```
var App = {
        init: function () {
            this.todos = util.store('todos-jquery');
            this.todoTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#todo-template').html());
            this.footerTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#footer-template').html());
            this.bindEvents();

        bindEvents: function () {
            $('#new-todo').on('keyup', this.create.bind(this));
            $('#toggle-all').on('change', this.toggleAll.bind(this));
            $('#footer').on('click', '#clear-completed', this.destroyCompleted.bind(this));
            $('#todo-list')
                .on('change', '.toggle', this.toggle.bind(this))
                .on('dblclick', 'label', this.edit.bind(this))
                .on('keyup', '.edit', this.editKeyup.bind(this))
                .on('focusout', '.edit', this.update.bind(this))
                .on('click', '.destroy', this.destroy.bind(this));
        },

    create: function (e) {
        var $input = $(e.target);
        var val = $input.val().trim();

        if (e.which !== ENTER_KEY || !val) {
            return;
        }

        this.todos.push({
            id: util.uuid(),
            title: val,
            completed: false
        });

        $input.val('');

        this.render();
    },
```

**My question**

I understand that when using jquery, `this` refers by default to “the element we called the method on” (`#new-todo` in this case), so in this code, we want to explicitly bind `this` to the object `App` instead.

In the example, both `this`s appear to follow the “left of the dot rule” and refer to `App`. So far, so good.

[image: Chrome debugger screenshot of this pointing to app in line 56]

[image: Chrome debugger screenshot of this pointing to app in line 57]

From this behavior, I expect that `this`, if *not inside* the callback function must refer to the parent `app`, (and `this` *inside* the callback function must default to the element with ID `#new-todo` unless bound to some other value).

Therefore, if I call `this.create` without binding it to anything, `this` should still refer to `App`, right? WRONG.

[image: Chrome debugger screenshot of this pointing to #new-todo in line 56]

[image: Chrome debugger screenshot of this pointing to #new-todo in line 57]

As you can see, the first `this` now refers to the element with ID `#new-todo`. (And the `this` in other event listeners below *also* refer to the jquery wrapped object!)

Can someone help me understand why?

Comment: There is more to this than just the element that called the method. See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @smartdroid that's what I'm hoping to understand. There may be some complicating factor (something like "calling '.bind()' creates a new object which is not subject to jquery's `this` mapping.") If so, I'd like to find out what that factor is.

Comment: Your "event handlers" aren't handlers - it would be in the format: `$("#new-todo").on("keyup", function() { this == $("#new-todo")[0] })`

Comment: @FlightPlan I do not claim to understand this fully. There is certainly a difference between class declaration and event binding. On top of that there is subtlety around strict or non-srict. Have you read the explanation at the link I gave?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem (with my question), so I thought I'd post the resolution in case it helps anyone in the future.

I realized that my initial understanding of `this` and `bind()` was correct, so I must be wrong about something else.

It turns out that
(1) I made an incorrect assumption about how the debugger works
(2) I needed to review when each part of the code ran

**(1) Debugger**

In the debugger, when I pause and linger my mouse over a variable, the debugger shows me a preview of that variable's value. I erroneously assumed that when the debugger pauses code execution, I'd see various values of `this` displayed, depending on the context (so a `this` in one method would differ from the `this` in another.) I see now that's not how it works. I believe `this` will show up as the same value everywhere and that value will be the value of `this` at the point where the script was paused. See attached gif for example.

**(2) Code execution timing**

When code execution paused for my breakpoint, I was already inside the `create` method, so the `this` in `this.create` and `.bind(this)` was reflecting the value of `this` within the `create` method.

[image]